# Bob's expensive day

Tags: logical-deduction

Bob leaves home with $50.

His birthday approaching, he goes to the neighbourhood bakery to order a birthday cake and pays \$29.95 for the cake, plus \$3.08 for the candles.

Then, he meets three friends in town and they all go grab something to eat: Bob takes a \$4.50 sandwich and a \$0.70 soda.

After that, they all go to the movie theater. Tickets cost \$10, but they can benefit from both an "under 25yo" \$2 discount for each one and a "Free ticket for every three tickets bought" offer, and split the bill equally between them.

They finish the afternoon at a bar, where Bob has two \$2.75 beers while chatting with his friends.

How old is Bob?

Comment: Is he in the USA?

Comment: I've tried to make this work on any country. I guess someone may find an exception, but you can indeed consider it's in the USA.

Comment: ok, thanks for info. I was asking re the legal age for drinking alcohol - it differs across countries.

Comment: This seems to lead to an unprovable assumption that he is <25, but they split the bill, so could potentially be a combination of ages. Are we able to assume his friends are the same age as him?

Comment: @JonStory - This was my first thought too... maybe I'm missing something, but the way I read it, the accepted answer could be true, or he could be turning 28 (11c per candle, or 44 @ 7c each, or 77 @ 4c, or 154, or 308 ;P), with one of his friends being <25. It just says "they" (as in collectively) benefit from a <25 discount. So, assuming only one of his friends is <25, then he spent \$29.95 (cake), \$3.08 (28 candles), \$4.50+\$0.70 (food), \$7 (movie - \$10+\$10+\$8+\$0/4), $2.25 (beer), for a total of \$47.48

Comment: @JonStory Oh, I see. Added "$2 discount _for each one_" to remove the ambiguity.

Comment: wait... 75 cent beers?  who cares how old he is

Comment: @TheodosiusVonRichthofen Allright, changed the beer price. I have to admit it was not the part of the puzzle I thought the most through.

Comment: What does Bob do with the remaining 27 cents?

Comment: @Michael He may shoot someone: [link](http://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2014/sep/8/sheriff-orangeburg-county-man-shot-over-27-cents/)

Comment: Hmm... Since the Cnadles could also be 2 Packs with a dozen candles for $1.54 each, you should probably clarify. Either that he payed his candles individually, or just by stating at the end something like "Assume that Bobs age can be deduced exactly from the things he bought"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Bob is 21.  He is under 25 (discount), older than 20 (beer), and the 3.08 for candles works out to 0.14 for each candle for his upcoming birthday (22)

Comment: Almost correct. Which means wrong :)

Comment: Yeah yeah, I remembered a factor I forgot.

Comment: And that's correct! I can't believe how fast that was...

Comment: @OxTaz don't forget to accept this answer.

Comment: Who buys candles individually?  I get that is the point of the question but I only see them sold in packs.  And where can I get $.75 beers in the USA?

Comment: Prime factors for 308 are 2,2,7,11, which means he could be 2,4,7,11,14,22,28,44,77,... I don't know of any country where it is legal to drink with 14, so 22 is the only answer - great riddle!

Answer (score 2):

He is celebrating his 22nd birthday.

He has to be at least 18 or 21 (depending on where he is) to buy the beers and less than 25 to get the discount. Dividing the candles by 22 gives a price of 14 cents per candle.

Comment: Actually, while making the puzzle I discovered that in some countries you can drink/purchase alcohol at 16, and had to consider that.